# access http within iframe from https parent window

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, iframe, ssl

I'm trying to solve a SSL issue which is caused by insecure content which is loaded within iframe. I have two domain addresses hosted on same server. I have SSL only for one domain. And when I'm on first site which use SSL I'm accessing second site which have no SSL. I want to find a way to solve this issue if possible. Again, both sites are hosted on same server.

Please give me suggestions or full answers how to solve this problem ?

I'm personaly thinking to use htaccess, but i dont know much about it. I want somehow to map the first site special url to second site, for example:

```
<iframe src="https://site1.com/special-url-to-point-to-site2">
```

and then with .htaccess to map to site2, so nothing is broken and everything works good.
I'm not sure if this is possible, I hope somebody understand what i mean and can help.

Comment: Apache supports reverse proxying which can be used for this.

Comment: I wouldn't want to do this in any case. You are basically trying to inject a non-secure site into your own secure site. I would say that would defeat the purpose of using SSL in the first place.

Comment: but both sites are hosted on same server, and there should be a way to use only site1 url which will point to site2 server path, or something like that

Comment: @ThiefMaster can you please post an answer how to do it ?

Comment: Both sites being hosted on the same server has nothing to do with a non-SSL domain serving content to an SSL domain that goes into the security layer and fails there. If both domains are on the same root folder you can internally redirect the site2 folder into site1 however site2 would not show in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive. You can't use it in the htaccess file but you *can* use the `P` flag in mod_rewrite as long as mod_proxy is loaded. Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^special-url-to-point-to-site2$ http://site2.com/special-url-to-point-to-site2 [L,P]
```

In your server/vhost config (for site1.com) you can use proxy pass:

```
ProxyPass special-url-to-point-to-site2 http://site2.com/special-url-to-point-to-site2
```

Make sure to checkout `ProxyPassReverse` which adjusts the url's in response headers to point them back to site1.